# Aggregate function in laravel 5.4 with joining

Tags: laravel, aggregate

I have two tables :

users table
{`id`, `name`}

payments table
{`id`, `user_id`, `payment`}

Here I want to join two tables and want to use `SUM(payment)` function group by `id`.

please give me a solution.

Comment: My code is ----    $payments = DB::table("users")
            ->select("users.id","users.name","users.title",DB::raw('SUM(payments.payment) as total_payment'))
            ->join("payments","payments.user_id","=","users.id")
            ->groupBy("users.id")
            ->get();

Answer (score 2):

You can do join like this way:

```
 $payments = DB::table('users')->join('payments','users.id','=','payments.user_id')->groupBy('users.id')->sum('payment');
//use DB to in you controller
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a queryBuilder for make de custom query.